# Using Native Page in Xamarin Cross Platform Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin Cross Platform Application in Visual Studio 2022. I have a Main Page where i want 2 buttons.

1. "Take me to Android Page" Button
2. "Take me to iOS Page" Button

I want to create a sample NATIVE page specifically in Android Project of this Cross Platform Application and one sample NATIVE page specifically in iOS Project within this Xamarin Cross Platform Application.

When I will click on "Take me to Android Page Button", it should take me to Natively designed Page of Android and when I will click on "Take me to iOS Page Button" then it should take me to Natively designed page in iOS Project.

I hope anyone can give me any reference or sample codes to achieve this goal.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin.Forms is designed to prevent the need to design each page for both platforms by using XAML to define shared layouts rendered at runtime using native controls. If you can expand your question to include reasons why you need to define fully native page layouts for each platform, that will help better inform answerers.

If you need the ability to create custom controls for each platform, consider [custom renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) which will allow you to define platform-specific behavior for individual views in your XAML pages.

Comment: We have Payment Gateway SDK for Android specific only that's why we need to use Native forms. Can you suggest or give me some hint how we can use them ?

Comment: To my knowledge Xamarin.Forms does not allow integrating directly with native libraries unless the developers have provided a wrapper or port to C# or you do the work to wrap the native library and compile it for your team's use.

Answer (score 1):

> When I will click on "Take me to Android Page Button", it should take
> me to Natively designed Page of Android and when I will click on "Take
> me to iOS Page Button" then it should take me to Natively designed
> page in iOS Project.

You can first find out what Xamarin Forms is and how it works.

From document [What is Xamarin.Forms?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms),we know:

> Xamarin.Forms is an open-source UI framework. Xamarin.Forms allows
> developers to build Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and Windows
> applications from a single shared codebase.
>
> Xamarin.Forms allows developers to create user interfaces in XAML with
> code-behind in C#. These interfaces are rendered as performant native
> controls on each platform.

And part [Who Xamarin.Forms is for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin-forms#who-xamarinforms-is-for) mentions that :

Xamarin.Forms is for developers with the following goals:

- Share UI layout and design across platforms
- Share code, test and business logic across platforms.
- Write cross-platform apps in C# with Visual Studio.

So,  the requirement you mentioned above is not invalid.

**In addition**,if you want to use native controls of the target platform in xamarin forms, you can use [Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to achieve this.

> Xamarin.Forms user interfaces are rendered using the native controls
> of the target platform, allowing Xamarin.Forms applications to retain
> the appropriate look and feel for each platform. Custom Renderers let
> developers override this process to customize the appearance and
> behavior of Xamarin.Forms controls on each platform.

**Note:**

> We have Payment Gateway SDK for Android specific only that's why we
> need to use Native forms. Can you suggest or give me some hint how we
> can use them ?

Xamarin.Android offers two ways to use these libraries:

**1.** Create a Bindings Library that automatically wraps the library with
C# wrappers so you can invoke Java code via C# calls.

**2.** Use the Java Native Interface (JNI) to invoke calls in Java library
code directly. JNI is a programming framework that enables Java code
to call and be called by native applications or libraries.

For more details, check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/ .